# font-face load faster?

Tags: css, font-face

I need some solution or suggestion to load faster fonts in a website.

something like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('myfont.eot');
    src: url('myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('myfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('myfont.svg#nexa_heavyregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

takes some moments to change the font-face while the html is loading or downloading the font-face url, some idea to load it faster?

Comment: faster uplink? load from a CDN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make it load faster because it depends on the network and browser font rendering but you can show a loading indicator of some sort while your font-face is loading using [FontLoader](https://github.com/smnh/FontLoader):

```
// Show an activity indicator while font is loading...

var fontLoader = new FontLoader(["myfont"], {
    "fontsLoaded": function(error) {
        // Hide the activity indicator and show the text.
    }
}, 3000);
fontLoader.loadFonts();
```

Here is a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gXtQA)